# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: xml

I am creating a sitemap XML from my database it's about videos sitemap. In XML, I am fetching the video title as `title` and description as `description`, but there are some titles and descriptions written in Thai, Portuguese, German, and other languages. While generating the XML through PHP I am facing a problem that says:

> "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed".

Generation of the XML stops after encountering this error.

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost/mydesk/sitemap.php
Line Number 24489, Column 69:
```

I observed it contained invalid characters like listed below, and I have replaced all types of these characters, but I realized there are other characters being used in other languages.

> Ð ž ´ Ø ¸ à ½ Ð ‰ ˆ Ù ° § ¼ ¡ ‹ ± … Â ³ è ¾ Ñ € ¦ ƒ Ñ ‡ ª Ñ Ï ¿ ¬ µ š † Ð ½ ¹ Œ ² Ð ¼ Î ¶ € Ð µ ] : å < * © > % â © # " ' ä æ ï ã Š ç › Š º Ž ¥ œ • ¤ ç ã ® ˜ ¢ ¨ ¯ £

Is there any way to handle this issue that supports all languages?

Comment: You will need to post more information.  "XML Parsing Error" occurs when something is trying to _read_ the XML, not when it is being generated.  Also, "not well-formed" usually refers to errors in the structure of the document, such as a missing end-tag, not the characters it contains.  Please explain more clearly exactly WHEN you get this error, and post the complete error message with stack trace.

Comment: Specify right encoding in the xml header. Something like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>.  And try again.

Comment: In header i am using already:

header("Content-Type: text/xml charset=utf-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n";

But no Luck :(

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this? I have a similar problem with people using characters in usernames

Comment: Got the same error. especially for German ö ä ü. What confuses me: this error only occurs with firefox. chrome reads the xml with no errors

Answer (score 9):

If you get this error message try view the page source by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
Usually there is a `"` symbol in wrong place. And check your html syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Can you open your xml document in a hex editor? If so see if it takes 1 byte per character or 2. If it takes 2 bytes per character you should try UTF-16 for encoding instead. If you do keep in mind that the only encoding you can guarantee a parser will support is UTF-8. Should support UTF-16 too but not all do.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in Firefox, parsing an SVG string, and it only disappeared with **"text/html"** as **mimeType**. I had tried 'image/svg+xml' and 'application/xml' before and found in the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString manual they are functionally equivalent anyway, so I tried..

Answer (score 1):

Use an `XML Validator` tool. You can find one online [here](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/)

In my case, it showed me the exact line and column of the error.